# How to restrict model predicted value within range?

Tags: amazon-web-services, linear-regression, amazon-sagemaker

I want to do linear regression with aws sagemaker. Where i have trained my model with some values and it's predicting values as per inputs. but sometimes it predicts value out of range as in i am predicting percentage which can't go less than 0 and more than 100. how can i restrict it here:

```
sess = sagemaker.Session()

linear = 
sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[boto3.Session().region_name],
role, 
train_instance_count=1, 
train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
 sagemaker_session=sess)
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=5,
mini_batch_size=100,
predictor_type='regressor',
epochs=10,
num_models=32,
loss='absolute_loss')

linear.fit({'train': s3_train_data, 'validation': s3_validation_data})
```

how can i make my model not to predict values out of range : [0,100].

Comment: One method is to constrain the model output to be within this range, which might be useful to prevent tiny overshoot values such as 100.001 or -0.0001. Another is to place simple "brick wall" bounds in the fitting function so that when it returns values outside [0.0, 100.0] then a very large value - and therefore a very large error - is returned. The "brick wall" method is somewhat crude, but often works in practice and is very easy to implement in code, but the output restriction may still be needed for small overshoot values.

Comment: @JamesPhillips thank you for your reply. but just wanted to ask if i can just clip model output within my range? is there any possible way with sage maker Estimator.

Comment: I personally do not use that software tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. You can implement the output_fn to "brick wall" your output. SageMaker would call the output_fn after the model returns the value to do any post-processing of the result. 
This can be done by creating a separate python file, specify the output_fn method there. 
Provide this python file when instantiating your Estimator. 
something like

```
sess = sagemaker.Session()

linear = 
sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(containers[boto3.Session().region_name],
role, 
train_instance_count=1, 
train_instance_type='ml.c4.xlarge',
output_path='s3://{}/{}/output'.format(bucket, prefix),
 sagemaker_session=sess)
linear.set_hyperparameters(feature_dim=5,
mini_batch_size=100,
predictor_type='regressor',
epochs=10,
num_models=32,
loss='absolute_loss',
```

> entry_point = 'entry.py'

)

```
linear.fit({'train': s3_train_data, 'validation': s3_validation_data})
```

Your entry.py could look something like

```
def output_fn(data, accepts):
    """
    Args:
        data: A result from TensorFlow Serving
        accepts: The Amazon SageMaker InvokeEndpoint Accept value. The content type the response object should be
            serialized to.
    Returns:
        object: The serialized object that will be send to back to the client.

    """
```

> Implement the logic to "brick wall" here.

```
    return data.outputs['outputs'].string_val
```